# Skip a video in youtube-dl if number of fragments are > n

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

youtube-dl typically downloads a youtube video very fast but when it comes to downloading live streams, its painfully slow.

Often live streams are processed as dash videos and we are given fragments.

Number of fragments depend upon the length of the video.

When the number of fragments reaches above 1.5k, the video downloads at a very slow pace.

Is there a way to skip a video if number of fragments pass a certain threshold? Or a way to download these dash videos faster?

I know if i use -f best, it will download the video fast, but it will only have 720p30fps as best, as opposed to 1080p60fps with -f 303+251.

Example: https://youtu.be/oqJPqwOMo7M

This video has above 3k fragments and is painfully slow to download than a normal non-dash video with the same length.